# Trying to count, but changes to 1

Tags: php

I am trying to make a counter. What I mean by that is a button that uses a XHTMLrequest and just runs this PHP.

My question is why is my counting code changing the value of the text document to the number `1`. If I just change the value to for example `24`, instead of adding 1 and changing the value to `25`, it changes the value to the number `1`.

```
<?php

$fp = false;
// Open file for reading, then writing
while ( ($fp=fopen('clicks.txt','r+'))===false ) {
    usleep(250000); // Delay 1/4 second
}
// Obtain lock
while ( !flock($fp, LOCK_EX) ) {    
    usleep(250000); // Delay 1/4 second
}
// Read Clicks
$clicks = trim(fread($fp,1024));
// Add click
$clicks++;
// Empty file
ftruncate($fp,0);
// Write clicks
fwrite($fp, $clicks);
// Release Lock
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
// Release handle
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$clicks++;` with `$clicks = $clicks + 1;`.

Comment: Wow... that worked! I think I got confused over some other languages.

Comment: Or `$clicks += 1;` to make it shorter.

Comment: You wont be able to notice a difference.

Comment: @C0deH4cker Of course not... Anyone would know that (common sense). But we can conclude your code is better because of less load time on server (not noticable, but whatever). Remember to minimize your code too.

Answer (score 2):

It is because when you read in the information from the file it is a string and needs to be converted to an integer before you can add 1 to it.

change:

```
$clicks = trim(fread($fp,1024));
```

to

```
$clicks = intval(trim(fread($fp,1024)));
```

Comment: What should I do to fix this problem - I am new to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I notice you `ftruncate` but never [`rewind`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php) the file. Remember that the pointer stays where it last read from, then truncating it makes the file 0 but the pointer remains the same.

Citing the PHP documentation:

```
<?php
$filename = 'lorem_ipsum.txt';

$handle = fopen($filename, 'r+');
ftruncate($handle, rand(1, filesize($filename)));
rewind($handle);
echo fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Note that PHP's example rewinds the file as well.

Comment: just call `rewind($fp)` after the `ftruncate($fp,0)` call and before your `fwrite`.

Comment: @user: Try without `ftruncate` call. Just simply `rewind` (any number you write will be equal or longer in length anyways);

Comment: This dose not work either - It might be something I do wrong.